# Strong password tip: review

Tags: passwords, password-protection

After having my gmail account hacked where i used for 9 years a too simple password i now decided to change all my passwords.

I picked up a quite complex password like

```
RumbleDance56
```

and to avoid having the same password on all websites i inserted the 1st letter of the website name in the password like this:

`RumbleGDance56` - for Google

`RumbleLDance56` - for Linkedin
... and so on

What do you think of this? The resulting passwords are strong and easy to remember.

Comment: [Correct horse battery staple](http://xkcd.com/936/) :)

Comment: If your using dictionary words (as in the example) then unfortunately not really.  The concept of a based password that you append to is useful though.  (Though some sites stupidly check for this!)

Comment: @cjb110 "Though some sites stupidly check for this!" - how website can detect this?

Comment: In my real password i don't use dictionary words but nicknames of friends, so that "RumbleDance56" is quite strong. My real question is about inserting "G" "L" "F" (Facebook) in a password as good technique or not.

Comment: "nicknames of friends" - note that with unusual nicknames (assuming that is some unusual word) it makes harder to break password in an automatic way. But it makes easier to be broken by people that you know.

Comment: @Bulwersator easily, probably via JavaScript on the form submission.  I pretty sure it was eBay where I found this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strong because you break up dictionary words by inserting single letters (hinting you to the wanted password by knowing where you wanna go) which should make it impossible to guess by comparing with dictionary words.

I try to proof this like:

google search 'mystrongpassword' > countless results,
query this 'mystrongApassword' > only a handfull shots,
and using 'mystron69assword' cant' be proper resolved by our biggest dictionary.

after testing this at google.de & .com i resume: you are good to go with your own encryption.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i followed the same logic. ANyway my account has been deleted, there is no way to restore it, i tried with google accoutn reovery but i am not able to reply to most qusetions ("when did u start using calendar?" - who knows?) anyway i survived a big illness in the past and i know what is most important in life, from now on i will chaneg my password more frequently (keeping the +'G' idea in the middle). Bye

Comment: 'mystron69assword' is not a strong password, its 3 words, if you can 'read' it as 3 words then so can the computer. Remember dictionary attack doesn't mean the actual Oxford English dictionary:)

Comment: -could you pls enlight me in counting 3 words in 'mystron69assword' -i recommend following my proofline to see the machine fail

Answer (score 1):

It is a very good idea to use different password on different websites. But note that you will have the same passwords for websites starting with the same letter.

But I would not describe "RumbleGDance56" as "quite complex password".

Comment: my google account was hacked after 9 years that my password was the meaningless word "serebum"; of course my main mistake was to never change password especially after google in recent times asked me to insert SMS sent confirmation code. A not trivial wwarning....

Comment: and about what you say "But I would not describe "RumbleGDance56" as "quite complex password", what i mean is that if you fill a typical registration form with that passowrd it says "strong"...

Comment: I use combination of four words + short random combination + substitute basing on website, but it may be an overkill.

Comment: @user193655 thats because it has capitals and a number, its a very basic/quick, and not particularly useful measure of complexity.  Any recognizable words (in any language) in a password means its not strong.